# Posets as Categories and Direct Systems of Objects?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

My algebra textbook brings the following example of category: Every poset $(X, \preceq)$ might be seen as a category as follows:

**Objects:**  Elements of $X$;

**Morphisms:** $\textrm{Hom}(a, b)=\rho^{a}_b$ if $a\preceq b$ and $\textrm{Hom}(a, b)=\phi$ otherwise;

**Composition:** $\rho^{a}_b\rho^b_c=\rho^{a}_c$;

**Identity:** of $a\in X$: $\rho^a_a$.

I didn't understand this very well. What are those $\rho^a_b$? Can anyone give me a concrete example.

I have already came across the notion of **direct system of abelian groups** and it sounds it is a functor between the above category and the category of abelian groups. Is there a notion of direct system of objects of an arbitrary category?

Thanks

Comment: The $\rho_a^b$ is just a notation. It means that there is a single morphism from $a$ to $b$ if $a \le b$. It doesn't really do anything. For the second question, the answer is yes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) and it is indeed a functor from the poset to the category

Comment: One way to think of those $\rho_b^a$ is as witnesses, that is to say, roughly speaking, they're proofs that $a$ is less than $b$. Of course, this does not strictly speaking work here, since there might exist multiple proofs of this fact (while you have at most one morphism between any pair of objects), meaning we have to think of it as having taken some sort of quotient. In the end this just means that you have a single "token" for each pair $a \preceq b$, with the order axioms then corresponding to closure properties of the category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this notation is indeed misleading. The text should rather be

> $\hom(a,b)$ has one element (referred by  $\rho^a_b$) $\,$if $a\preceq b$, and $\hom(a,b)=\emptyset$ otherwise.

So that we could write $\ \hom(a,b)=\{\rho^a_b\}$ if $a\preceq b$.

Basically, given a poset $(X,\preceq)$, in the associated category whenever $a\preceq b$, there is a unique arrow $a\to b$, named $\rho^a_b$ here.

For the second question: **yes**, a direct system of objects in category $\mathcal A$ is just a functor $\mathcal X\to\mathcal A$ where $\mathcal X$ is a *directed* poset, regarded as category. 
(Here 'directed' means that any two elements has common upper bound.)

Comment: Indeed I had summarized the part $\textrm{Hom}(a, b)=\rho^{a}_b$, in the book it was like you said. Thanks for the answer =)